# QGIS Map Layer Definition Symbology Lost

Tags: qgis, layers, symbology, layer-file

We have a 'Desktop Research' QGIS map file that is automatically added to each project folder using a folder setup batch file. The file has our Base Datasets symbolised as per our ArcGIS Base Dataset layer file. The overall symbology is saved to a Layer Definition file.

Recently certain members of staff have found on opening a particular project map that the symbology for all the vector layers in the map has been lost. This includes not only the base data but also the project data. Points revert to red, lines to black and polygons to blue. Raster layers retain their symbology.

I've tried opening multiple maps, with and without the issue, to see if there is a common theme linking the maps that have lost the symbology. The only common theme linking the 'broken' symbology is there is no rendering information within the QGS file when viewed in Notepad which is to be expected, I suppose.

The image shows the issue, the left snip is the 'broken' symbology, the right snip how it should look. [image]